# Ternary operator's precedence and assignment in Java

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Why does `bar` method below fail to compile while `foo` is fine?

[image]

Comment: Just because that is how the rules are defined for Java. Java is not C#, so there is no reason to expect that whatever works in C#, works in Java in the same way.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Java isn't C#, and *vice versa*. You haven't stated which line gave the compilation error.

Comment: @Jesper C# comparison was unnecessary, I rephrased the question.

Comment: Even without comparing it to C#, my answer still holds: it's only because that's how the rules are defined for Java. See: [Java Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of the [precedence rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) of Java. Assignment has a lower precedent than either `?` or `:`, so it get's evaluated last.

That means that case `bar` gets parsed like this:

```
return (s != null ? s : s) = "bar";
```

Which doesn't make sense to the compiler.

If you insert the parenthesis I show above, you'll see that the compiler fails with the same error message in the same spot, because the two are effectively the same.